# cannot change reference object of the parameter in method

Tags: c#

```
    void Swap(Empolyee lhs, Empolyee rhs) {
        Empolyee tmp = lhs;
        lhs = rhs;
        rhs = tmp;
    }
```

I want to swap two Employees using this method, but it doesn't work. Although it works after imposing *ref* keyword on the parameter, I want to know the reason why the former doesn't work. Because every object in C# is reference-type, I thought it should work. I am looking forward to your help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your qs?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void Swap(ref Empolyee lhs, ref Empolyee rhs) {
    Empolyee tmp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = tmp;
 }
```

Then call:

```
  Swap(ref lhs, ref  rhs);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this method should work, but my question is: now that the parameter is already a reference-type, why should we further impose the "ref" keyword.

Comment: When you pass any parameter to a method, you are simply passing a copy. Reference types are just memory location values that point to larger pieces of data. So, in effect, you were passing a copy of the location, which doesn't effect the variable outside of the method. Using `ref` means that you are passing the *actual* variable and any changes are made to that variable are reflected outside the scope. That link that zenwalker posted above contains more information about this behavior.